# Javascript variable added at wrong place along with strings in innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

I happen to be attending a HTML+AJAX+JQUERY course for the first time. We have an array containing the days of the week (arrWeek). Trying to add the days to an Option element, we first chose to follow this steps to add options to a **Select**:

```
objSelect.innerHTML+= '<option value="' + i + '">'; 
objSelect.innerHTML += arrWeek[i];
objSelect.innerHTML += '</option>\n';
console.log(arrWeek[i],objSelect.innerHTML);
```

It happens to show the following result in the console:

```
<option value="-1">-- Choose a day --</option>
<option value="0"></option>Monday
<option value="1"></option>Tuesday
<option value="2"></option>Wednesday
<option value="3"></option>Thursday
<option value="4"></option>Friday
<option value="5"></option>Saturday
<option value="6"></option>Sunday
```

Please note the name of the day is **after** the **/option**  .

In the end we managed (of course) to do it differently, getting the proper result for the objSelect. However we would like to know if anybody can help on **WHY** the variable is put **AFTER** (?!?!?!).

Thank you all very much!

Comment: Interesting question, I believe when you do `objSelect.innerHTML+= '<option value="' + i + '">'; ` browser automatically closes the tag itself (as for this brief moment opening tag is all that is inside). Then you append your day after and `+= '</option>` probably does nothing. To solve it you can append whole string at once or use a temporary string that you assign later when it's fully constructed. It's also generally advised to use document.createElement and asign a value/text node to it instead of innerHTMLs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The browser parses the HTML as soon as it changes so when you first write `<option value="...">` to the inner HTML the browser will parse it before the next line where you try to add the content gets run. When it parses it, the browser will see an unclosed tag and then close it for you. The variable gets added after this automatically closed tag and the ending tag gets ignored because it doesn't have an associated opening tag.

You can fix it by writing the complete `<option>` tag including its content in one concatination:

```
objSelect.innerHTML+= '<option value="' + i + '">' + arrWeek[i] + '</option>\n';
```

But really, it's a much better idea to do these kind of things by manipulating the DOM directly with `document.createElement()` and `.appendChild()`:

```
var opt = document.createElement('option');
opt.value = i;
opt.appendChild(document.createTextNode(arrWeek[i]));
objSelect.appendChild(opt);
```

Comment: Thanks @Mikael Lennholm for the answer. Perfectly clear!!! Thank you also for alternative solutions!!!

Answer (score 0):

try the following (add the string at once)

```
objSelect.innerHTML += `<option value="${i}">${arrWeek[i]}</option>\n`;
```

as for why it might not have worked before, possibly:

let the beginning innerHTML be `<option value="-1">-- Choose a day --</option>`

now, when u do `objSelect.innerHTML+= '<option value="' + i + '">';`, the innerHTML becomes

```
<option value="-1">-- Choose a day --</option>
<option value="0"> // here
```

now, since the last option tag has no closing, it might add the following automatically (without your help), and mutate the string to become

```
<option value="-1">-- Choose a day --</option>
<option value="0"></option>
```

then you add your next line in `objSelect.innerHTML += arrWeek[i];`

and it becomes

```
<option value="-1">-- Choose a day --</option>
<option value="0"></option>Monday
```

then when you add the `</option>` tag at the end, it ignores it as it has no place in the code (there is no `option` tag to close)

This is all because the browser parses the html as soon as you change it!

next time, use appendChild() and document.createElement() instead!

Answer (score 0):

I will mention Mikael's comment to make the solution clear:

"The browser parses the HTML as soon as it changes so when you first write  to the inner HTML the browser will parse it before the next line where you try to add the content gets run. When it parses it, the browser will see an unclosed tag and then close it for you. The variable gets added after this automatically closed tag and the ending tag gets ignored because it doesn't have an associated opening tag"

Thanks @Mikael Lennholm for the answer. Perfectly clear!!! Thank you also for alternative solutions!!!